# Find element with XPath

Tags: xpath

I have the following markup:

```
<div>
 <div>Question1</div>
 <div>
  <button type="button">No</button>
  <button type="button">Yes</button>
 </div>
</div>

<div>
 <div>Question2</div>
 <div>
  <button type="button">No</button>
  <button type="button">Yes</button>
 </div>
</div>
```

The following XPath expression locates two yes buttons:

```
//div/div/button[text()='Yes']
```

However I only want the `Yes` button of the first div as in:

```
//div/div[text()='Question1']
```

How can I locate that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Use**:

```
//div[div[. = 'Question1']]
   /div/button[@type = 'button'][. = 'Yes']
```

This selects any `button` whose string value is `"Yes"` and whose `type` attribute has string value `"button"` and (the `button` element) is child of a `div` that is a child of a `div` that has a `div` child with string value `"Question1"` .

Answer (score 1):

Your can target the first `button` like this (if you don't want to hardcode `Question1` into your query):

```
(//div/div/button[text() = 'Yes'])[1]
```

See also [MSDN XPath Examples](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256086.aspx).

Comment: This xpath expression found the right yes button, but i can't build upon the order of the divs so i have to hardcode 'Question1' somehow.

Comment: @ImrePetroczki In that case your question was a little misleading and some of the other answers will be what you need.

Answer (score 1):

Tested and working for me with your snippet:

```
//div/div[preceding-sibling::*[position() = 1][.="Question1"]]/button[.="Yes"]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try //div/div[text()='Question1']/button[text()='Yes']

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```
/x:html/x:body/x:div[1]/x:div[2]/x:button[2]
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:
`//div[div[text()='Question1']]/div/button[text()='Yes']`
OR
`//div[div/text()='Question1']/div/button[text()='Yes']`
This selects the button having text='Yes' and having a parent that has a child div with text='Question1'

Also if you are interested in the first div no matter the text, use:

`//div[1]/div/button[text()='Yes']`
and to be more specific you should specify the parent:
`/div[1]/div/button[text()='Yes']` - if it's root (as in your example)
`//parentNode/div[1]/div/button[text()='Yes']` - if it's *`parentNode`*

Comment: The `"Question1"` text is in the preceding sibling `div`, not the parent `div` of the `button`.